# Is reading one-past-the-end pointer allowed in a constant expression when short-circuit disable its evaluation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, short-circuiting, constant-expression

Consider example:

```
template <char>
struct foo { };

int main() {
    foo<""[0]?""[1]:'\0'>{};
}
```

The code compiles in both [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zHRugWUSE97P2Dxg) and [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dwej5McM6ZhYkc3d), but should it really? I know the expression `""[1]` doesn't need to be evaluated as it was short-circuited. But standard isn't very clear if the expression can actually qualify as a core constant expression. Relevant [[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) and especially part:

> If e satisfies the constraints of a core constant expression, but
>   evaluation of e would evaluate an operation that has undefined
>   behavior as specified in [library] through [thread] of this document,
>   it is unspecified whether e is a core constant expression.

raises my doubts...

Comment: What's unclear? The evaluation of this conditional wouldn't have undefined behaviour since `""[1]` would not be evaluated.

Comment: Leave the standard alone. Invoke common sense. Consider this expression: `(x? (10/x) : 0)` where `x` is some integral constant expression. Should it be an OK constant expression?  Now assume `x` is known to be zero. Is it OK now?

Comment: @n.m. Wow that example really makes it straightforward!! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the extract actually covers that:

> If `e` satisfies the constraints of a core constant expression, but ***evaluation of e would evaluate an operation that has undefined behaviour*** as specified in `[library]` through `[thread]` of this document, it is unspecified whether `e` is a core constant expression.

There is actually *no* undefined behaviour in the expression `""[0]?""[1]:'\0'` because the only problematic bit `""[1]` is never *actually* executed. In fact, the entire expression can simply be optimised to `'\0'` without adverse effects.

The *reason* it's not executed comes from the standard itself (e.g., `C++11 5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond] /1`:

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4). It is evaluated and if it is true, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression,
>   otherwise that of the third expression. ***Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated.***

Since `""[0]` will always evaluate to false in the boolean context, the second sub-expression is never executed. It's really no conceptually different from the expression:

```
false ? (1/0) : 42
```

in that you'll never actually have to worry about the possibility of divide-by-zero.

Comment: So you're saying there is no restriction on the core constant expression that each of its subexpression need to be a core constant expression?

Comment: @W.F., there may well be *other* restrictions preventing your `e` from being a core constant expression (I haven't looked), but that sentence in the standard appears not to be the issue you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

To answer that, one would have to quote the start of this paragraph, which says:

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of
>   e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of
>   the following expressions:

And since the rules of the abstract machine promise the evaluation of the out of bounds access won't happen ([[expr.cond]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#1)):

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is
>   contextually converted to bool. It is evaluated and if it is true, the
>   result of the conditional expression is the value of the second
>   expression, otherwise that of the third expression. **Only one of the
>   second and third expressions is evaluated**.

There's no undefined behavior, so it must be a core constant expression. Or at least, it's not the bullet you quoted which disqualifies it.

Comment: I think I got your point... Can't find any bullet that the expression would break in obvious way. Probably my mind doesn't work like `the abstract machine` at least not today... :)

Comment: @W.F. - That abstract machine is the source of much confusion, my own included. So I don't blame you or anyone, on any given day :)